# Ubuntu 14.04 doesn't show last modification hour when paste conflicting files

Tags: nautilus

I have just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I am working on some C files which I created a week ago.

I tried to copy those files into another backup folder on my USB key, where they were already present. Since the name of the files is the same, it asked me if I wanted to replace the files in that folder or if I wanted to ignore the copy/paste operation.

However, the window for the conflicting files compares only the date of the last modification of the two files, and not the hour. This is very bad since it is possible that I override the file written in the afternoon with the one written in the morning.

Is this normal in 14.04? Is there a way to solve the problem?
Thanks.